# Is there any method to use with Pyspark to read a MongoDB collection as an RDD and NOT as a dataframe?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

I use Pyspark to access Mongo. My task is pretty simple: export Mongo to hdfs. Here is my code:

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder.appName("Mongodb-Exporter") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "xxx") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.database","xx") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.collection","xx") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").load()
df.write.format("json").save(sys.argv[1])
spark.stop()
```

Everything is working well until I run into this problem:

```
com.mongodb.spark.exceptions.MongoTypeConversionException: 
 Cannot cast STRING into a ArrayType(StringType,true) (value: BsonString{value=''})
```

This happened because my collection has a field that has multiple kinds of values, e.g.

```
document1:{"name":"ross"};
document2:{"name":["joey","monica"]}
```

I am so confused. Is there any way I can read Mongo and return an RDD? I don't want dataframe, I don't care its schema, but it seem dataframe cares much.

P.S: I know Java or Scala could do this, but how should I do with Pyspark? I am new to StackOverflow, hope someone can help me, thank you!